# Using a database in an offline single user application

Tags: database, software-design

Is there any scenario or kind of Database that would facilitate the kind of IO that a serialized set of data from a program does?

I ask this because this year I dealt with Object Serialization, and databases while being more convenient technically, didn't seem practical to use given that there was just one user per application and it needed to be deployed onto users machines

Comment: Have you heard of http://www.sqlite.org/ ? A no-install SQL database built to be embedded in applications. It's used all over the place: http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html

Comment: What about xml? What is the order of data you are planning to handle?

Comment: Not sure what kind of orde, as an example a list of spells from an RPG, with 500 entries and other aspects of a text based game